# SQL query to select dates between date - 30 days

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a query here that im trying to make but I'm having troubles getting it working.

So essentially what I want to do is to make a query to search between a date given minus 30 days... so anything between the date given minus 30 days.

In my query I want to make sure that `RSLVD_DTTM` equals to `TICKETDATE` or anywhere between 30 days prior to `TICKETDATE`.

EXAMPLE.

```
RSLVD_DTTM = TICKETDATE BETWEEN TICKETDATE - 30 DAYS
```

any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS (Oracle, SQLServer, PostgreSQL etc) is this? They each tend to have their own date-handling functions.

Comment: Have you tried `(RSLVD_DTTM > TICKETDATE - 30) AND (RSLVD_DTTM <= TICKETDATE)`?

Comment: @ConradFrix: Oracle, for one.

Comment: @MarkBannister my mistake I thought it did. TeraData is apparently another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify a DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL

```
where RSLVD_DTTM between TICKETDATE  - interval '30' DAY and TICKETDATE
```